# Where is the Class class declared/how to forward declare it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c++, forward-declaration, metaclass

I cannot compile my because of this error in my header:

> error: expected identifier [1]
>
> -(void) removeAllEntitiesOfClass:(Class)class;

with the caret pointing to the lowercase class.

Removing this function makes it compile again.

My class is a subclass of NSObject, which has public methods that use Class, so I thought this would automagically be declared.

I also tried changing Class to Class* and forward declaring with @Class Class, and this doesn't work - it says it is a redefinition because I am changing the type.  Apparently Class is a typedef'd struct pointer.  I'm not sure how to forward declare that here, and I seem to recall it can be nasty business to forward declare a pointer typedef.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, and tell me what file to import or how to forward declare.

```
@interface GameState : NSObject {   
...
}
...
-(void) removeAllEntitiesOfClass:(Class)class;   
@end
```

Comment: Weird. It should just work. Have you #imported Foundation in the header file?

Comment: It compiles fine on my end... you may have set an erroneous architecture or target maybe?

Comment: @Costique: yes, I tried <Foundation/Foundation.h> to no avail.

Comment: @Peter: thanks for testing, I'll look at my configuration.  The target is iOS.  Although, the project has been building for quite a while though without config changes.

Comment: Apologies for not specifying that I was working in obj-C++, editing question tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your header is visible in an Objective-C++ translation. In C++, `class` is a keyword. To fix this, change the parameter's name from `class` to some non-keyword.

Comment: ah, yes, it makes sense.  Interesting how the method name 'class' doesn't cause an error (as with new), but parameter names do.